# How to disable Safari's new "feed://" redirection for feeds?

Tags: rss, google

I'm sure some people really love that new feature, but I use Google Reader so it's driving me batty. Not to mention that as a tech guy, I might want to actually view an XML feed once in a while (like for instance, [Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/) update feeds).

So how do I stop Safari from redirecting the normal XML feeds to their "feed://" pseudo-protocol?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it used to be possible in Tiger/Safari 2.0 to disable this using `defaults write com.apple.Safari DebugSyndicationEnabled -bool NO`. ([source](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=92027)) I cannot get this to work in Lion/Safari 5.1, however.

Your best bet seems to be to set the default feed reader (Safari → Preferences… → RSS) to something that gives you XML source.

Comment: There is no Safari->Preferences->RSS in Safari 7

Comment: That answer was written long before Safari 7's release.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case that would be useful, disable RSS feed in Safari 5 :
Safari top menu --> Preferences --> RSS --> uncheck both boxes next to "automatically update articles in"
Done.